# Random Forest performed significantly better than other models for Multimodal data, Why?

Tags: classification, random-forest, multimodality

Sorry about the vague question.
I have multimodal human biosensory data, from eyes, body position and EEG. 
In my classification, Random Forest performed better than Neural Networks, SVM or Naive Bayes..
Is there any reason for this or any literature that backs this outcome? Is this to be expected? I understand that this may be due to my data and not a general outcome, however as I could not find any evidence or literature to back this statement, I was wondering if you knew of any research with similar results or if the general structure of a Random Forest leads to better outcomes with MM data?

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: I did not come across any source on why RFs are more efficient on multimodal data. Yet, RFs (and other ensemble techniques) generally work well and even better when some features in the dataset are very strong. RF, through random feature sampling, gives a chance to other features as well. You can see if this is the case by observing feature importance on your dataset.

Comment: You should exactly explain your train/validation/test strategy and also the dimension of your data. Otherwise, answering this question is like random guessing.

Comment: Thanks both! helpful to know the right and wrong of the question I'm asking. I did find this paper which seemed encouraging. https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-24553-9_85